# How to stop nginx sending status code partially written files to browsers?

Tags: rsync, nfs, nginx, sftp, inotify

I'm uploading video files to my Nginx server at `/var/www/static`.

The files are sent from a separate machine. Sometimes these are large files, but are typically sent via an internal network.

For reasons not relevant, I'm able to use only a single command on the other machine to transmit the file.

What seems to be happening is that sometimes browser clients get a HTTP status 206 (partial) from Nginx instead HTTP status 200 and the file loading and displaying.

I have tried copying the file from server to server firstly via NFS, then directly via SFTP, then by saving it to local disk where `inotify` is watching a directory and running `rsync` to send the file over whenever new files are saved to that directory.

In all cases the 206 problem remains.

It happens less when I use SFTP - presumably this is the fastest way to get the file there? But it still happens.

Can anyone suggest how I can prevent this happening?

Comment: you could upload the files to a temporary directory and after file is on the web server then move it to /var/www/static